# After alert condition when condition changes from true/false. Currently alerts if either condition is true. Not when it changes

Tags: conditional-statements, alert, pine-script

This is part of a pine script for tradingview. On the script after '//Condition', I want an alert to generate only when the condition changes from long to short or short to long. Not the end of each candle as it does now, as one condition is always true.
This has been changed to a study.

```
threshold = input(title="Threshold", type=float, defval=0.0014, step=0.0001)

buying  = l3_0 > threshold ? true : l3_0 < -threshold ? false : buying[1]
///// T edit
selling = l3_0 > -threshold ? true : l3_0 < threshold ? false : 
selling[1] //// T edit END

hline(0, title="base line")
bgcolor(l3_0 > 0.0014 ? green : l3_0 < -0.0014 ? red : gray, transp=20)
bgcolor(buying ? green : red, transp=20)
plot(l3_0, color=silver, style=area, transp=75)
plot(l3_0, color=aqua, title="prediction")

/////     Stragegy     
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//longCondition = buying
//if (longCondition)
    //strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

//shortCondition = buying != true
//if (shortCondition)
    //strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

/////     Alerts     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////alertcondition(condition, title, message)

```
//Condition
long  = l3_0 > 0.0014
short = l3_0 < -0.0014


alertcondition(long, title = "ANN Long", message= "ANN Long")
alertcondition(short, title = "ANN Short", message= "ANN Short")
```

Comment: What language are you using here? Can you try to describe what you want to achieve in details?

Comment: This is pine script

Comment: Please add that tag to your question (or accept my edit), so people can reach your question easier

Comment: On the script after ' //Condition', I want an alert to generate when the condition changes from long to short - lo short to long

Comment: Hi Zeet. I get limited to 150 letters.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should describe it in the description, not in the title

Comment: Thanks Zeet. Fist time user on stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at a smaller example using MACD. We want to go **long** whenever `delta` is `>= 0` and go **short** whenever `delta` is `<0`. Also, we would like to stay in our position unless the opposite signal is triggered (enter once and wait for the opposite signal).

Your code looks like below:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)

// Get the inputs
MACDLengthMACD = input(title="MACD Length", defval=9, minval=1, maxval=100)
fastLengthMACD = input(title="MACD Fast Length", defval=12, minval=1, maxval=100)
slowlengthMACD = input(title="MACD Slow Length", defval=26, minval=1, maxval=100)

// Standard MACD calculations
MACD = ema(close, fastLengthMACD) - ema(close, slowlengthMACD)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLengthMACD)
deltaMACD = MACD - aMACD

buySignal = (deltaMACD >= 0)
sellSignal= (deltaMACD < 0)

plotshape(series=buySignal, text="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=red, size=size.small)
```

In this case, you will get multiple BUY or SELL signals because `buySignal` and `sellSignal` will be `true` as long as their conditions are `true`.

[image]

However, those signals should be `true` for one bar only in order to trigger only one BUY or SELL signal. To accomplish that, you can use another variable (`isLong`, `isShort` in below code) and use history reference operator `[]` to determine if you were previously LONG or SHORT.

Then, only trigger your BUY signal if you are not already LONG and only trigger your SELL signal if you are not already SHORT. This way you will get only one BUY or SELL signal.

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)

// Get the inputs
MACDLengthMACD = input(title="MACD Length", defval=9, minval=1, maxval=100)
fastLengthMACD = input(title="MACD Fast Length", defval=12, minval=1, maxval=100)
slowlengthMACD = input(title="MACD Slow Length", defval=26, minval=1, maxval=100)

// Standard MACD calculations
MACD = ema(close, fastLengthMACD) - ema(close, slowlengthMACD)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLengthMACD)
deltaMACD = MACD - aMACD

// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
buySignal = not isLong and (deltaMACD >= 0)

// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short
sellSignal= not isShort and (deltaMACD < 0)

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

plotshape(series=buySignal, text="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=red, size=size.small)
```

This will result in:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for posting this 2 years ago. Still works and is still helping people.

Comment: Glad you found it useful @RobbieSmith