# alert, true or false, changes from true to false and false to true

Tags: pine-script

TradingView PineScript code. Need an alert when it changes from true to false and false to true.

```
//@version=2
study

threshold = input(title="Threshold", type=float, defval=0.0014, 
step=0.0001)



buying = l3_0 > threshold ? true : l3_0 < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="base line")
//bgcolor(l3_0 > 0.0014 ? green : l3_0 < -0.0014 ? red : gray, transp=20)
bgcolor(buying ? green : red, transp=20)
plot(l3_0, color=silver, style=area, transp=50)
plot(l3_0, color=aqua, title="prediction")

//longCondition = buying
//if (longCondition)
//    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

//shortCondition = buying != true
//if (shortCondition)
//    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Have changed it to a study. As a strategy it gave an alert and plotted the direction on the chart. Changed it to a study but the alert is only supposed to go when it changes. On  my study it alerts every candle and not on the change over. Anything I tried just gives a long or short on every candle.

Comment: Did you see my answer to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56287886/7209631

Comment: which row do you think is giving you the alert ? most of your code is commented out.

Comment: Thank you Baris. Yes I did receive your answer. Spent days trying to add to my script but could not make it work. I am still learning code. Know the basics and can understand some of the code. Tried hacking it around but could not make it work. Could you have a look at this for me? Any suggestions greatly received.

Comment: Hi Reportgunner. The code was originally a strategy. Hence the commenting out. I left that in as I thought it might help. The strategy enter/exit is what I am after in a study. Only when it changes from true to false or false to true. Needs to be exit buy and enter sell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [change()](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_change) function to check if a variable has changed.

```
//@version=3
study("Custom alert condition", overlay=true)
my_variable = close > open

alertcondition(change(my_variable), title='Triggers when close is above the open or vice versa', message='Candle color changed!')
// this is here because a study chart requires at least one plot, bgcolor or barcolor call
// setting the bar color to na (i.e. N/A) does nothing
barcolor(na)
```

You can then go to the alarm clock icon in the upper right and create a new alert that uses this custom condition. There are options to trigger it once per minute, once per bar or other.

---

Here's a testing alert condition to see if you have created the alert correctly, set it to trigger every minute and it should trigger quickly.

```
//@version=3
study("Testing condition", overlay=true)
alertcondition(close, title='Triggers when close changes', message='Close has changed!')
barcolor(na)
```