# Alert IF condition flow not right

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling to find the right IF condition to trigger an alert.  The idea is that the current active price (close) value go past the long or short points it must trigger the respective alert.
Preferably, e.g. only one sell when it passes the sell_level. If it passes the buy_level, in the same realtime bar, then trigger the buy.  If the current price go past the sell_level again, in the same bar, after a buy, then it should trigger a new sell alert.

I have played around with many options but just can't get it right.  This is my code:

```
// goto SELL
if low < sell_price
    buy := false
    sell := true
// goto BUY
else if high > buy_price
    buy := true
    sell := false

if close > buy_level
    alert('buy: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(sell_level), alert.freq_all)
else if close < sell_level
    alert('sell: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(buy_level), alert.freq_all)
```

[Basic Flow example][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycUZ3.jpg

Edit 1: amended code

```
// buy only if buy_sig triggered and not already long
buySig = actSell and not isLong

// sell only if sell_sig triggered and not already short
sellSig = actBuy and not isShort

if buySig
    isLong := true
    isShort := false
    alert('buy: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(sell_level), alert.freq_all)

if sellSig
    isLong := false
    isShort := true
    alert('sell: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(buy_level), alert.freq_all)

plotshape(series = buySig, text = "BuySig", style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.large)

plotshape(series = sellSig, text = "SellSig", style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.large)
```

Edit 2: varip

```
// see if long
varip bool isLong = false

// see if short
varip bool isShort = false

bool buySig = false
bool sellSig = false

// buy only if buy_sig triggered and not already long
buySig := not isLong and Buy

// sell only if sell_sig triggered and not already short
sellSig := not isShort and Sell

// alert conditions
if buySig
    if isLong == true
        isLong := false
    else
        isLong := true
    isShort := false
    alert('BUY price: ' + str.tostring(sell_level), alert.freq_all)
else if sellSig
    isLong := false
    if isShort == true
        isShort := false
    else
        isShort := true
    alert('SELL price: ' + str.tostring(buy_level), alert.freq_all)
```

Comment: What's the issue you have at the moment?

Comment: Two issues:  (1) if the close goes past a point, it continues to generate an alert. I understand it will happen because with every new tick the script re-calculates. If I change the alert to freq_once_per_bar it negates the second requirement.  (2) If there is a spike(s) in the opposite direction (and back again), another alert is not generated. So there could possibly be multiple buys/sells in the current bar. Sorry I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: I have added a basic flow diagram - may help to understand what I want to do

Comment: @vitruvius an old post of yours is the closest I could find to my scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284820/after-alert-condition-when-condition-changes-from-true-false-currently-alerts-i/56287886#56287886

Comment: But I still get multiple alerts - its messing with my head... LOL
I added the changed code in the section above

Comment: My old answer and the one you linked will not help you. I feel like you need a `varip` variable. See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/)

Comment: Yeah. Kinda make sense. The question is "where"? I tried it a few places and either get no alerts or still multiples.

Comment: @vitruvius : your other code (link above), seems to be working as I want it, with the varip. See Edit 2 above.
The only "funny" leftover, is that sometimes it still don't activate in a realtimebar.  I suspect it is because the price_level is recalculated before it comes to the buy/sell signal, thus causing it not to activate the alert or only activate it on the next bar (when it crosses that point).  Unfortunately, getting this particular scenario, takes a long waiting time...